# inter process comunication in bash read commands in multiple background functions

Tags: bash, function, readline, ipc, coprocesses

I'm trying to get the following code to read from a main input then read that in one function then be able to send that into the input of another function but i am having trouble getting it to work and it NEEDS to be inputted into the read command to be able to be parsed

```
coproc test {
for i in $(seq 0 9)
    do
        sleep 1
        echo $i
done
}
input() { while read -u 3 gr
    do
        echo sent: $gr # this should send to output function
done
}
output() { while read idk
    do
        echo received: $idk | sed s/r/R/ | sed 's/5/five/' # this should receive from input function
done
}
exec 3>&${test[0]}
exec 4>&${test[1]}
input <&3 &>4 & # remove >&4 to see output
export input_PID=$!
output <&4 &
sleep 11
exec 3>&- 4>&-
echo finished
```

I've tried every kind of redirection of the fd but nothing seems to work, please help, the idea is that a user will be able to (based on what the output function reads) send commands into the input function without needing to duplicate the code for each function, and vice versa (input function can send to output function as well), sending to fd3 or fd4 doesn't work as it seems to bypass read itself and send directly to the command that is receiving the final output

Note that this is just a minimal example, the full use is here:

Basic process layout of the script (each indent represents the source depth or sub process depth):

```
Code_Bash
    . ./modules/module_controller
        . ./modules/module_trap
            . ./modules/module_finish
        until [[ $FIN == 1 ]] ; do
        . ./modules/module_loader
            . ./modules/module_colors
            . ./modules/module_tracker
            . ./modules/module_config
            . ./modules/module_kill_all_panes
            . ./modules/module_irc_session
                . ./modules/module_input
            . ./modules/module_irc_read
                . ./modules/module_output
                . ./modules/module_handler
                . ./modules/module_user_input
            . ./modules/module_array
            if [[ -z $IRC_NC_PID && $IRC_FIN == "0" ]] ; then
            . ./modules/module_coproc_nc
            . ./modules/module_rest_of_script
            fi
            . ./modules/module_null
        done
```

https://github.com/mgood7123/UPM/blob/master/Files/Code/modules/module_loader (this is continuously executed)

https://github.com/mgood7123/UPM/blob/master/Files/Code/modules/module_coproc_nc

https://github.com/mgood7123/UPM/blob/master/Files/Code/modules/module_irc_read (core module ran in separate background process)

https://github.com/mgood7123/UPM/blob/master/Files/Code/modules/module_irc_session (core module ran in separate background process)

https://github.com/mgood7123/UPM/blob/master/Files/Code/modules/module_rest_of_script (THIS RUNS THE BACKGROUND FUNCTIONS FOR THE IRC_READ AND IRC_SESSION)

Comment: Your code and description are incomplete. What is `${test[0]}`? Statements like "iv tried every kind of redirection of the fd but nothing seems to work" are generally not very useful. Put in the question what you have tried.

Comment: @HaukeLaging `${test[0]}` is the coproc output but, indeed, OP has so much "tried every kind of redirection of the fd" that the current script does not make any sense at all, besides being completely buggy. It's hard to understand what you want to achieve Clark.

Comment: Clark, If following our answers, you have further questions, do not change your original question drastically as you did, as it invalidates our answers (I have reverted your edits). Just open a new question. You may link the two questions in their description.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you mix up input and output:

```
exec 3>&${test[0]}
exec 4>&${test[1]}
input <&3 &>4 &
```

You open both `&3` and `&4` for writing only. But the first can only read. Reading from `&3` fails because you have opened the fd for writing only. What you need is

```
exec 3<&${test[0]}
```

Comment: ok, ill try that

Comment: i get line 13: read: read error: 4: Bad file descriptor
when i try read -u 4 idk, and changing to 3<&${test[0]} doesnt seem to work

Comment: @ClarkKent You have to read from `&3` i.e. it must be `read -u 3`. You can only write to `&4`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what cannot work in your script:

```
exec 3>&${test[0]}
```

As the coproc output, `${test[0]}` is a file descriptor meant to be read from, not written to. Assuming you mean `3<&${test[0]}`

```
input <&3 &>4 &
```

First, `&>4` means "redirect stdout and stderr to a file named 4", you probably mean `>&4`. Now, FD #4 being the input of the `test` coproc (which is not read by test BTW) that redirection makes little sense.

```
output <&4 &
```

If there wasn't a typo, FD #4 would be an output file descriptor (bound to the coproc's stdin), you cannot read from it.

---

Now I'll try to give you a working code, assuming you want:

- one background process `input` that reads from FD #3 and sends everything to `output` with "sent" prepended to each line.
- another background process `output` that reads whatever `input` sends, prepends "received", does some string processing and writes the result on stdout

Normally, this would be as simple as this:

```
test() for i in {0..9}; do sleep 1; echo $i; done    # No coproc

input() while read gr; do echo sent: $gr; done       # Reads from stdin, not FD #3

# output() unmodified

exec 3> >(input | output)
test >&3
```

But I'm under the impression that, for whatever reason, you want to spawn `input` and `output` separately and put `test` in background. Then try this:

```
exec 4> >(output)
output_PID=$!

exec 3> >(input >&4)
input_PID=$!
exec 4>&-

test >&3 &
wait
```

Comment: ill try that aswell

Comment: @ClarkKent Remove `-u 3` from your `read` command for this to work, I assumed `input` was reading from stdin.

Comment: i get no output when i do exec 3> >(input | output) ; test >&3     even when i remove -u 3

Comment: both of the read commands to not need to have -u right?

Comment: it outputs nothing no matter if i do read -u 3 or read -u 4 for either of the functions ;-;

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tell you that the coproc was not necessary any longer, read my updated answer

Comment: am i doing something wrong?

Comment: this is correct right? Recieved: sent: 3

Comment: No `read` command needs `-u`, your function should remain regular filters, reading from stdin and writing to stdout. I have tested the code in my answer and it writes `Received: sent: 0` ... `Received: sent: 9` with `Received: sent: five` in the middle.

Comment: if i do "echo sent: $gr >&2 ; echo $gr" would that achieve an output of "sent: 1 (new line) Recieved: 1"

Comment: so to apply the same method my my other script i how would i modify it while still maintaining its functionality, it starts netcat in the background (i think) with its input and output redirected into file descriptors, as follows : exec 3>&${IRC_NC[0]} ; exec 4>&${IRC_NC[1]} #(via coproc IRC_NC { ... } ; irc_session <&1 >&4 & #(this is what handles user input from the terminal (like for example parsing commands that arnt normally accepted) and sending it to netcat) ; irc_read    <&3     & #(reads output from netcat)

Comment: in order to send input from irc_session to netcat do no redirection in the commands following read (however i can also do >&2 to acomplish the same thing wich is also a bit confusing), to redirect to terminal instead of nc i do >&2 ; in the irc_read i can redirect output to the netcat by using >&4 and to terminal by doing no file redirections, so in order to possibly preserve these redirections (or if possible improve them to make them easier and less confusing between functions)

Comment: so how would i go about this without overwriting fd's 3 and 4 while also making sure that one does not cause the other to hang due to waiting for input or output and so i can send input from the irc_read function into the input of the irc_session function so it can be parsed then sent to netcat

Comment: in wich both functions are implimented in the same way as in the test script except with alot more code after the read commands like output formatting and input and output command recognition

Comment: in wich both functions are implimented in the same way as in the test script except with alot more code after the read commands like output formatting and input and output command recognition, but the primary goal is to somehow (if possible) merge the test script with the main code so if irc_read (output) recieves a command it is sent into the irc_session (input) function to be parsed then sent to netcat while also allowing the irc_session (input) to freely be able to send input to netcat without waiting for input to be recieved from the irc_ (output)

Comment: revised my question

Comment: No, if you have further questions, then create new question(s).

Comment: oki https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/392811/inter-process-comunication-in-bash-read-commands-in-multiple-background-function